# Having an issue with antd datepicker not displaying value

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, antd

Im having an issue with the datepicker component. I have tried multiple things but the date I am passing will not display in the datepicker. I just set the fields  in the beginning of my component. The warrantynotes field shows just fine. I get different errors depending on what I try but mostly :
TypeError: date.clone is not a function
format

```
 form.setFieldsValue({
      datepurchased: e.datepurchased,
     
      warrantynotes: e.warrantynotes,
    })


  <Form.Item
   name={'datepurchased'}
   label="Date Purchased:"
   // defaultValue={moment(warranty.datepurchased)}
   //  format={dateFormat}
   // defaultPickerValue={moment(warranty.datepurchased)}
                >
   <DatePicker
   onChange={handleChange}
    // defaultValue={moment(warranty.datepurchased)}
    // format={dateFormat}
    // defaultPickerValue={moment(warranty.datepurchased)}
  ></DatePicker>
 </Form.Item>
```

Comment: how is format the date?

Comment: '2021-01-07' is the date and its format

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change your code, use `defaultValue` instead `defaultPickerValue`

```
const { DatePicker, Space } = antd;

function handleChange() {}

const myDate = "2021-01-07";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Space direction="vertical" size={12}>
    <DatePicker onChange={handleChange} defaultPickerValue={moment()} />

    <DatePicker onChange={handleChange} defaultValue={moment()} />

    <DatePicker onChange={handleChange} defaultValue={moment(myDate)} />
  </Space>,
  mountNode
);
```

Comment: hi @AlTheLazyMonkey i can not open the link. It spins forever. Do you mind pasting your code? Im pretty sure though I tried default value, thats why I commented out the different things I have tried with a //....